# Mounting outlet on drywall furred out from cement

Tags: electrical, basement, receptacle, basement-refinishing

I am in the process of adding an outlet to a wall in a previously renovated basement.  The wall is drywall, mounted to furring strips which are attached to the cement wall.

My two options as I see it are:

1. Externally mounted box run horizontally like wiremold or EMT and a handybox, or
2. Cut a hole in the drywall, mount a handy box directly to the cement. Fish NM down vertically between the drywall and cement wall into the handybox.  It leaves about 3/4" of the box jutting out from the wall.  Patch around it, paint, good to go.

Which would be more "proper"?  Any code concerns?

Edit: added image of the completed project.

[image]

Comment: you don't say how thick the furring strips are.  Code requires conduit if the wires are less than 1.25 (sometimes 1.5) inches from the back of the drywall.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  1" furring strip.  Does that leave me with surface conduit or would armored cable be possible?

Comment: It's certainly ok to remove a bit of concrete foundation to get a box to fit flush.  Just messy and hard to do without proper tools.

Comment: @Paul -- there's also no requirement for boxes to fit flush with the wall -- they just can't be recessed into it.

Comment: Some relevant discussion regarding BX vs EMT vs plate near the finished surface: http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/38680/4565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three choices here:

1. Run the NM cable in-wall with a sheet steel protector at least 1.6mm thick between the cable and the wall surface (to keep those pesky nails away)
2. Run conduit in-wall -- a 3/8" trade size EMT should squeeze down there OK although you'll be tight on wire fill with that.  You might be able to fit 1/2" EMT -- I'd try it at least, and use the 3/8" if 1/2" doesn't fit in the gap.
3. Run surface raceway or conduit, if you'd rather the industrial aesthetic.

All three will meet Code -- it really depends on cost and what skills and materials you have available to you.

Comment: Excellent...thank you for this answer. Is BX/MC cable not allowed? The drywall is already installed, trying to not break up the wall if possible, and I don't know how I'd get the sheet metal or EMT back there.  If that's the case, maybe I go industrial.  :-)

Comment: @PeterJ -- MC cable would work, but you'd still have to put the nail plate in there, and NM's like half the price :P

Comment: @Paul -- could you clarify what you're responding to?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel moved comment.

Comment: Just to put a little closure here, I went with #3:  wiremold (basically square EMT that extends from existing outlets.). Worked great.

Comment: @PeterJ -- just as a belated sidenote, "wiremold" is the same thing as what I mention when I say "surface raceway"